# git apply does not update working copy

Tags: git

I need to apply patch on a branch. Some changes from patch may be applied cleanly and some may not.

I use following command:

```
git diff hash1 hash2 -u | git apply -3
```

For some reason it does not do anything. It tells me some patch errors etc. but there are no changes in my working copy. That is strange, patch contains new files, which are definitely may be applied on working copy but they are also not created.

I tried to replace apply with `patch`

```
git diff hash1 hash2 -u | patch -p1 --binary
```

And it worked. I mean it patched some files, created others etc. but I would like to merge failed hunks with `git mergetool` so I need to use `git apply`.

What is wrong with it and how can I fix it?

P.S.

I can apply changes just in a single file:

```
git diff hash1 hash2 -u -- path/to/file | git apply -3
```

Then apply succeeds and file is patched.

Comment: Did you try git cherry-pick --strategy=recursive? It seems odd to go through diff and apply.

Comment: @lynxlynxlynx, I do not need to apply each commit, I want to apply all changes as a single diff.

Comment: Add -n if you don't want the commit to be recorded and just its changes applied. I don't understand your distinction well.

Comment: @lynxlynxlynx, distinction is in amount of times I need to resolve conflicts. Branch which I take commits from contains my changes + someone else's changes. My changes should apply cleanly and other changes I will merge. To use `cherry-pick` I will need to filter out my commits in the `hash1..hash2`.

Comment: So there's more than one commit involved and you prefer one larger conflict than several smaller, ok. You could try just pulling it in and specifying --squash.

Comment: @lynxlynxlynx, Can I pull from a local branch?

Comment: of course, eg. `git pull . otherbranch` to merge it into the current working tree/branch.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for git apply's --reject option?

From the man page:

```
--reject
    For atomicity, git apply by default fails the whole patch
    and does not touch the working tree when some of the hunks
    do not apply. This option makes it apply the parts of the
    patch that are applicable, and leave the rejected hunks in
    corresponding *.rej files.
```

However, I don't see what this has to do with git mergetool...